# Minified version of browserify does not work

Tags: javascript, gulp, babeljs, browserify, babel-polyfill

The uncompress version works fine, but the compressed and minified do not.

```
gulp.task('adtag', function () {
  // set up the browserify instance on a task basis
  var b = browserify({
    entries: './src/adtag/main.js',
    debug: true
  }).transform(envify({
        NODE_ENV: 'production'
  })).transform(babelify.configure({
        plugins: ['transform-object-assign']
  }));

  return b.bundle()
    .pipe(source('smaatoAdTag.min.js'))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
        // Add transformation tasks to the pipeline here.
        .pipe(uglify())
        .on('error', gutil.log)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/adtag/'));
});
```

If i "uncompress" the minified version, everything works

Comment: Are you attempting to output ES6? I see you only have `transform-object-assign` in your list. Uglify does not support ES6.

Comment: No, i attempt to output ES5

Comment: Do you have other presets configured like `es2015`?  You also need to clarify "does not work" so it is unclear what issue you are having. What is the actual error you get?